# Wilson's Theorem for Primality Testing wrong implementation?

Tags: language-agnostic

```
/**
*    Finds whether a given number is prime or not
*    using Wilson's Theorem
*/
boolean isPrime(long n){
    if( fact(n-1) % n == (n-1) % n  ){ return true }
    else{ return false }
}
```

This is my implementation of [Wilson's Theorem for primality](http://theoremoftheweek.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/theorem-27-wilsons-theorem/). It works well till `n = 19` and fails for `n = 23` and afterwards.

What is wrong here?

I am using this way of writing the formula as a reference:
[image]

Comment: According to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem the theorem is `fact(n-1) % n == -1 % n` and not `fact(n-1) % n == (n-1) % n`?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck Haven't checked Wiki. It's supposed to be `-1 % n`

Comment: But in your code you write `(n-1) % n`? :)

Comment: @AndreasBrinck see edit :) It's a congruence, not an equals sign :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, missread the theorem

Comment: 1. Shouldn't it be `fact(n-1) % n == n-1`?, 2. Check the defition of the `%` in the language of your choice, 3. Check that the factorial doesn't overflow your datatypes

Comment: (1. above shouldn't really matter though)

Comment: @AndreasBrinck The `fact()` is overflowing

Answer (score 0):

Look at the numbers (19 - 1)! (=6402373705728000) and (23 - 1)! (=1124000727777607680000).  Now compare these numbers to MAX_LONG (=9223372036854775807).  @AndreasBrinck's comment was correct.